# You roll three fair 8-sided dice (each face of a die contains a number from 1-8).

Tags: probability

You roll three fair 8-sided dice (each face of a die contains a number from 1-8). Answer the following:

a) What is the probability that you get exactly twice a number which is greater than 6?

b) What is the probability that no die lands on number 8?

so x is a number from 1-8

And 2x > 6

so x = 4,5,6,7, or 8

a) p(exactly 2 >6) = 9/64

b) p(8') = (7/8)^3 = 343/512

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't think "$2x > 6$ is what they mean by "Exactly twice a number greater than $6$" They probably mean that of the three dice, exactly two of them have a result greater than $6$.

Comment: Are my answers correct?

Comment: Your second answer is correct.  Your first answer is unclear because your reading of the problem seems uncertain.  I agree with @Arthur that what is most likely intended is that they want at least two of the throws to be $7$ or $8$.

Comment: Note:  I have a typo in my last comment.  I should have written "exactly two of throws to be $7$ or $8$."

Comment: I got 9/64 for part a). Is this correct?

Comment: @JackieF I don't think so, can you show what you've done? I think the probability to get one number greater than 6 (so a 7 or 8), is $\frac{2}{8}$ . So if you want two number greater than six, you have $\frac{2}{8} \times \frac{2}{8}$. And you want exactly two numbers, so the third dice should be 1,2,3,4,5 or 6. So $\frac{2}{8} \times \frac{2}{8} \times \frac{6}{8}=\frac{3}{64}$

Comment: Oh, maybe you are right. If you add the combinations to that (${3} nCr {2}$), you have $\frac{9}{64}$